# Sort data in different components ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I am trying to put a button that when clicked will sort the information in descending order.

I have the components separated, in this one I have the button and the click for it to perform the sorting (in the console you can see that it is already doing it).

```
    const [ascending, setAscending] = useState(true);

    const handleSortDesc = () => {
        for (const info in data){
            const auditorium = data[info].representations;
            const sortedDataAsc = [...auditorium].sort((a, b) => (a.regularSeatsLeft - b.regularSeatsLeft));
            console.log('Sorted Data (Descending):', sortedDataAsc);
            setAscending(ascending); 
        }
    };
     
    return (
        <div className="auditorium-container"> 
            {data.map(d => (
                <div key={d.name} className={`auditorium auditorium-${d.id}`} >
                    <div className="auditorium-header">
                        <h2>{d.name}</h2>
                        <button type="button" className="button" onClick={handleSortDesc} >
                            SORT DESC
                        </button>
                    </div>   
                    <Representation 
                        data={data}
                    /> 
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

[console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhKzX.png)

But I don't know how to send that new ordered information to the component where it renders and prints the information.

```
const Representation = ({ data }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {data.map(auditoriums => (
                <div className={`auditorium-${auditoriums.id}`}>
                    {auditoriums.representations.map(r => (
                        <div className="representation">
                            <span className="time">{r.date} - {r.time}</span>
                            <span className="label">Seats Remaining:</span>
                            <span className={r.regularSeatsLeft > 0 ? 'available' : '' }>
                                {r.regularSeatsLeft || 0}
                            </span> 
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>  
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: At the end of your `for..in` loop, you're calling `setAscending(ascending)`, which is just passing back in the current state. Might you have meant to pass in something else?

Also, when you're `map`ping the data, you can `sort` it and then chain on the `map` operation.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to pass the sortedDataAsc const.
I have already made this modification but I still don't know how to send the sorted information to my Representation component.

Comment: First way: You can do it by creating a new variable in handleSortDesc func, and then it should be equal to the data like (const sortedData = data). Then update its value with the sorted one; ==> sortedData[info].representations = sortedDataAsc . After the for loop is done, set the new variable to the state => setData(sortedData); -- Second way: set ascending state as true after clicked button and send it to the component as a prop. Then if props.ascending is true, map the data after sorting like ==> [...auditoriums.representations].sort((a, b) => (a.regularSeatsLeft - b.regularSeatsLeft)).map

Comment: @OnurDoğa You could answer the question and receive reputation with this much information - just suggesting.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @hokwanhung. I didn't have time to create an answer post actually, when I saw the question. So I added a comment to be helpful quickly. But you are right, I created the answer post now. I hope it'll be useful

Answer (score 2):

**First way:**

You can do it by creating a new variable in the `handleSortDesc` function. Then update its value with the sorted one. After the for loop is done, set the new variable to the state. Then you don't need to use the ascending state as well since it'll not affect functions.

```js
const handleSortDesc = () => {
     const sortedData = [...data];
     for (const info in sortedData){
         const auditorium = sortedData[info].representations;
         const sortedDataAsc = auditorium.sort((a, b) => (a.regularSeatsLeft - b.regularSeatsLeft));

         sortedData[info].representations = sortedDataAsc;
         console.log('Sorted Data (Descending):', sortedDataAsc);
      }

      setData(sortedData);
    };
```

**Second way:**

You would like to sort all the components ascending or descending by clicking the button. For this, makes sense to store the ascending state and change it when the user clicks the button and sort it by state's value. Set the ascending state as true/false after clicking the button and send it to the component as a prop. Then if `props.ascending` is true/false, map the data after sorting by descending/ascending.

**- Set the ascending state as true/false when the user clicks the button:**

```
<button type="button" className="button" onClick={() => handleSortDesc(true)}>
   SORT DESC
</button>
```

**- Send state to the related component as a prop:**

```
<Representation data={data} ascending={ascending}/>
```

**- Then map it after sorting if the ascending prop has a true value:** (You can sort it descending if it is false)

```js
const Representation = ({data, ascending}) => {
return (
    <div>
        {data.map(auditoriums => (
        <div className={`auditorium-${auditoriums.id}`}>
            {(ascending ? 
                 [...auditoriums.representations].sort((a, b) => (a.regularSeatsLeft - b.regularSeatsLeft)) :
                     auditoriums.representations).map(r => (
            <div className="representation">
                <span className="time">{r.date} - {r.time}</span>
                <span className="label">Seats Remaining:</span>
                <span className={r.regularSeatsLeft > 0 ? 'available' : '' }>
                        {r.regularSeatsLeft || 0}
                </span> 
            </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    ))}
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Just be aware that the "first way" implementation you propose is mutating current state references. ***All*** state that is being updated *necessarily* needs to be shallow copied into new object references. `sortedData[info]` is mutated.